# static listview check a checkbox on populating based on a values

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, mono

i want to ask how i can check a checkbox in a listview based on the values of a entry column.

Sadly after some hours of google i couldn't figure out a solution that fits the bill. Since most seem to be based on Windows Forms.

Here is the current code:

```
        SDVVersion.Text = SDVMMVersion;
        SMAPIVersion.Text = SDVMMSettings.SmapiVersion;
        // Createing  columns
        Gtk.TreeViewColumn CBColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        CBColumn.Title = "Active";

        Gtk.CellRendererText CBCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        CBColumn.PackStart(CBCell, true);

        Gtk.TreeViewColumn NameColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        NameColumn.Title = "Name";

        Gtk.CellRendererText ModsNameCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        NameColumn.PackStart(ModsNameCell, true);

        Gtk.TreeViewColumn AuthorColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        AuthorColumn.Title = "Author";

        Gtk.CellRendererText AuthorCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        AuthorColumn.PackStart(AuthorCell, true);

        Gtk.TreeViewColumn VersionColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        VersionColumn.Title = "Version";

        Gtk.CellRendererText VersionCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        VersionColumn.PackStart(VersionCell, true);

        Gtk.TreeViewColumn DescColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        DescColumn.Title = "Description";


        Gtk.CellRendererText DescCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
        DescColumn.PackStart(DescCell, true);

        // Add the columns to the TreeView
        activeMods.AppendColumn(CBColumn);
        activeMods.AppendColumn(NameColumn);
        activeMods.AppendColumn(AuthorColumn);
        activeMods.AppendColumn(VersionColumn);
        activeMods.AppendColumn(DescColumn);

        activeMods.Model = new ListStore(typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string));
        // the column checkbox is created
        Gtk.CellRendererToggle valueCb = new CellRendererToggle();
        CBColumn.PackStart(valueCb, true);

        CBColumn.AddAttribute(valueCb, "bool",0);
        NameColumn.AddAttribute(ModsNameCell, "text", 1);
        AuthorColumn.AddAttribute(AuthorCell, "text", 2);
        VersionColumn.AddAttribute(VersionCell, "text", 3);
        DescColumn.AddAttribute(DescCell, "text", 4);

    }

    internal void RefreshTreeView()
    {
        ModStore.Clear();

        foreach (ModInfo Mod in Mods) // Mods = the modstore, modInfo mod = the json tempalte from where it is read
        {
            ModStore.AppendValues(Mod.IsActive.ToString(), Mod.Name, Mod.Author, Mod.Version);
if(Mod.IsActive == true)
//checkbox = checked

        }
    }
```

i would appreciate any help offered from links to examples to code examples itself.

~yuuki

Comment: Is that Xamarin project code?

Comment: yes, mono do be more precise

Comment: why you are using gtk then? what platforms you are targeting?

Comment: windows, linux and Mac